# android-Why custom actionbar doesn't fill the width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

this is my custom layout xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/weather" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/like" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gps2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gps2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gps1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gps1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my actionbar java code:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mCustomView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
         actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         actionBar.setIcon(null);
```

this is the activity theme in manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

This is the result :

[image]

as you can see , the black layout doesn't fill the width , I don't know why. How can I make custom actionbar to fill the screen width ?

Comment: do you have menus enabled ?

Comment: android:adjustViewBounds remove this, will it work ?

Comment: @Paul  I removed it , nothing changed

Comment: @SpringBreaker  there is nothing on my activity for creating menues , I mean I don't have onCreateOptionsMenu .

Comment: @mahdiyamani  how u resolved ?

Answer (score 2):

In your actionbar java code, replace

```
actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
```

with

```
actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView, new Toolbar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Hope this help you.!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

and remove

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `android:setcontentstart` and `android:setcontentend` to `0dp`.